# Consulta de dados iguais em datas diferentes

Tags: php, mysql

Eu gostaria de saber como posso trazer alguns dados do BD. Como por exemplo nome do cliente, ID e data. 
Na empresa que trabalho ha Ordens de Serviço, mas algumas dessas OS são de clientes iguais(mesmo cliente mas OS diferentes).
A empresa quer saber se esse cliente voltou em menos de 24hrs para fazer uma nova OS. 
Como posso fazer isso?

```
SELECT id,cliente_id,
DATE_FORMAT(datcriacao, '%d-%m-%Y'),
count(cliente_id)
FROM sis_ordem_servico
group by cliente_id
order by id
```

isso é oque tenho por enquanto, mas esta trazendo apenas a data de uma OS e não de todas como preciso

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione a estrutura da tabela, sem saber quais campos especificos fica complicado de elaborar um resposta certeira.

Comment: Coloca a parte do `create table ... ` use o link editar que está em baixo dos quadrinhos azuis. [Aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) tem um dicas de como funciona o site aproveite para ler é bem rapidinho.

Comment: Provavelmente como é uma dúvida de consulta , você vai refatorar sua sql, com algum dado do PHP , informe mais, sobre a estrutura da tabela .